# inject js to head (with full-code in script)

Tags: javascript, html, web, header

I want to add a script to the head of a site so the the head of the target html looks like so `<head><script type="text/javascript">*some code...*</script></head>`.

---

With this script works that perfect:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    script = document.createElement('script');

script.src = 'http://www.example.com/example.js';    
head.appendChild(script);
```

---

But i don't want to use any link in source.

So i'm tried to add some code like this:

```
    function addJS(jsCode) {
    var styleElement = document.createElement('script');

    styleElement.type = 'text/javascript';

       (scriptElement.javascript) {
        scriptElement.javascript.jsText = jsCode
        scriptElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(jsCode))

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptElement);
}

var jsCode = '';
jsCode += 'code';
jsCode += 'some more code';
```

---

But I've failed. That script is not working.

How can I add a  Element to the head of any html site like this?
Would be great if someone could help me.

Comment: To clarify, you want to dynamically add javascript from an external file to the head of an html document?

Comment: Are you using jquery? Also, is the javascript source in the same domain as the site?

Comment: I don't prefer to use jquery, but if there no other way to do this I also suppose that.

Answer (score 11):

Just tried this and it seemed to work. Try

```
function addJS(jsCode) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');

    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.innerText = jsCode;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}
```

Demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/dF445/2/)

Comment: Thank you, but how I could add a script with more than on line & funtion & some "" in it?

Comment: @Michael Updated my fiddle. Take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I try this and it dosen't work. http://jsfiddle.net/dF445/ (The shortcut.js for this script is already in the page...)

Comment: @Michael What is shortcut by the way. No such object exists in the window object

Comment: Thats just a example with "" in it... I only to make sure that the script whichs writes the code to the head accepts also "" in the code.

Comment: @Michael updated my example. If your string is wrapped in double quotes remember you can only use single quotes within you javascript code. Or vice-versa, if you wrap the code in single quotes you can only use double quotes inside your string.

Comment: Thank you for the update, the code works. But the target site keep on relaodloading when script is enable. (I add it with a userscript.)

Comment: I think I only should add a if arry to the script which check if the code is injected, but with my limited Javascript knowledge I don't really know how to do this. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery

```
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        script = document.createElement('script');

    $(script).attr('type' , 'text/javascript');    
    head.appendChild(script);
    $(script).append("alert('Hello')");
```